# Should I have redundant unit test

Tags: unit-testing, testing

For example, the server would response

```
{
   name: "mike",
   age: "12",
   sex: "male"
}
```

In my code, I only use name, so my code would be string name = json["name"];

For my unit test, should my unit test case be the actual json result above or just

```
{
   name: "mike",
}
```

Since I only parse `name` field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When writing unit-tests you should be thinking for each test, what the purpose of each test is.

In your example, the goal of one test might be to test if your code extracts the name properly from the server result.  But, as the handling of keys and values is part of the language, you don't have to test that this is working for a mixture of keys and values: The expression `json["name"]` does the actual magic for you.  Therefore, you can keep the 'pseudo' server response quite simple - it does not have to be like an actual server response.  That is, just using `{ name: "mike", }` would be OK.

There will likely be more test cases, for example to test that your code handles error situations properly, for example if the server responds with an answer that does not have a name - or have two or more names - or looks totally garbled.  Again, you would have to define some 'pseudo' server results.

At some point, however, you will have to test your code against the actual server - then you are, however, leaving the realm of unit-testing and enter into integration-testing.

Answer (score 0):

in unit test case, the actual result will be 
{
   name: "mike",
}

Comment: But is it bad practice to include redundant test case? Since the server will never return { name: "mike"}, would it be good idea to include actual result even though it will be redundant?